# How to pass an expression without eagerly evaluating it to a subset assignment function in R?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to implement a function in R that mimics Pythons tuple unpacking, that is to unpack elements from a list automatically into environment variables.

The little problem is that a function should get a list-like expression as an argument without parsing and executing it like `tuple_unpack(a, b)` or `tuple_unpack(a=c, b=d)` (when there are no variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in the environment).

As functions in R use lazy evaluation of their arguments it is possible and I managed to code it to a function that is intended to use with the pipe like `source_list %>% tuple_unpack(newVar1, newVar2)`.

However, I'd like to make it nicer by coding it into a subset assignment function (those in the `func<-` form) so it can be used like that: `tuple_unpack(newVar1, newVar2) <- source_list`.

But this way I get the error `object 'newVar1' not found` (or alternatively `target of assignment expands to non-language object` for kwargs list). The error is thrown before R starts to execute the function so I cannot stop the evaluation in any way from inside the function. Actually I'm not even sure if there is a solution - can subset assignments functions be lazily evaluated at all? Or is it only possible for normal functions?

For more context, here is the working solution which doesn't use subset assignment (stripped to essential parts, full code available [here](https://github.com/JantekM/JantoTools/blob/7d1c6c5195b7120189711e35f1dd2c2b4dbd81ea/R/unpack.R)):

```
uc <- function(source, ..., envir = parent.env(environment())){
  dots = substitute(alist(...))
  target_names = names(dots)
  #some non essential sanitation here

    uc_positional_(source, ...,
               envir = envir)
  }
}

uc_positional_ <- function(source, ..., envir = envir){
  dots = substitute(alist(...))
  target_names = names(dots)
  #more sanitation

  for(ind in 2:length(dots)){
    if(substr(dots[[ind]], 1,1)=='_'){ # a way to skip the assignment for target variables named with underscore
      if(substr(dots[[ind]], 2,2)=='_'){ # double underscore to ignore the rest of the argumenys
        break
      }
      else{
        next
      }
    }
    assign(dots[[ind]] %>% as.character(), source[[ind-1]], envir=envir) # the actual assigning the list
  }
}

list(a=1, z=0) %>% uc(b, c) # works fine
```

And here is a theoretical way to implement it using subset assignment (which doesn't work):

```
"uc<-" <- function(..., source , envir = parent.env(environment())){
  browser() # not invoked as error if thrown before entering the function
  
  # the rest of the function
}
uc(x, y) <- list(a=1, b=0) # eagerly evaluated instead of lazily
```

Comment: Hello Jantek, see the [zeallot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zeallot/index.html) package. Assignment `<-` hardly works for that purpose, as it essentially do ```assign("x", `uc<-`(x, value= list(a=1, b=0), y)) ``` (an argument named "value" must be defined in uc<- and a variable x must exists in  current environment)

Comment: @RicVillalba Ok, the package works pretty much the same but that's not the point of the question. The tuple unpacking was more for context (as you can see, I have it working, just in a slightly different way). The question is about lazily evaluating arguments from a subset assignment function.  And also, if it worked just by calling the `assign(...)` as you wrote it would be a problem because it could be evaluated lazily so no problem there.

Comment: That's just not going to work for R. The `fun(x)<-z` syntactic sugar requires that the `x` value be assignable because R essentially translates that to `x <- \`fun<-\`(x, z)`. That's not something you can change. That first parameter is special. That's why zealot has to create a new operator `%<-%` because you can't change the behavior of `<-`

Comment: Even if "fun<-" does not evaluate x, it must exist in the environment prior to assignment. So you will always get "object 'x' not found" or similar if it is not the case. I think it is hardcoded in R to give semantic validity to assignment functions.